# How can I show the branches in `git log -- dir`?

Tags: git-log

I can run `git log -- doc` in, for example, [this fairly small repository](https://github.com/alire-project/alire). However, the branches are not displayed unless the tip of that branch made a change inside the directory I specify. I would like to see the branch names displayed on the latest commit on that branch that touched the directory.

This is similar to how, in GitExtensions, you can request the 'History of a directory / file' while still also seeing the branches involved. It is especially useful when you are resolving a difficult merge/rebase conflict, or tracking down a bug in that code, because you can see the branches which the other modifications were on, so you also know if particular changes were already merged into master or not.

I specifically need a way to output this on the commandline, such as by passing parameters to `git log`, or a custom shell script, because the output of git log is used by my git GUI ([vim-flog](https://github.com/rbong/vim-flog/issues/47)).

Answer (score 0):

I got a sort-of fix from someone; good enough to mention, but it shows a branch for every commit, regardless if there is some more recent commit on the branch also visible:

Add %S to your pretty format, e.g.:

```
$ git log --graph --all --format='(%S) %h %s' -- doc
```

The --all is essential, otherwise it is always 'HEAD'.

```
* (refs/heads/master) 2f8558b user-changes.md: document SPDX license expressions (#683)
* (refs/heads/master) 9ad7f20 user-changes.md: Add markers for releases (#684)
| * (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) 2d08fa4 Typos
| * (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) 7b7e342 Typos
| * (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) a81c5b1 Add more documentation for crate configuration
| * (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) 3071227 Crate configuration: new manifest syntax
| * (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) 4eb8180 catalog-format-spec.md: start documentation of crate configuration
|/
* (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) a689ee3 Automatically narrow down dependencies given as "any" (#675)
* (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) 70add12 Warn about ^0.x dependencies (#669)
* (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) c763b00 Rename `alr list` to `alr crates` (#671)
* (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) 8c1e893 Clarify current behavior of actions (#672)
* (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) 185b1e1 Remove use of build/clean relocations (#667)
* (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) b9e8a64 Alire.Properties.Licenses: Add support of SPDX expression  (#629)
* (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) ccab133 Allow unknown enum values in index manifests and new `index --check` (#656)
* (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) 226e9b6 Alr.Commands.Edit: add support for custom editor (#611)
* (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) ca526e6 policies.md: add best practices (#597)
* (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) bcca503 Migration of an existing Ada/SPARK project to Alire (#598)
* (refs/remotes/origin/feat/crate_config) 7b9b7f9 Change Windows installer icon (#589)
* (refs/tags/v0.7.0) b5ad3d2 Fix the `depends-on` example in the catalog spec (#581)
* (refs/tags/v0.7.0) 378baa6 doc/getting-started.md: replace "setenv" with "printenv" (#576)
* (refs/tags/v0.7.0) e5c1ba9 Added paragraph about adding an ALR badge (#574)
* (refs/tags/v0.7.0) cc594c0 catalog-format-spec.md: fix gpr-set-externals description (#572)
* (refs/tags/v0.7.0) a824354 reviewed for English grammar, spelling, etc. (#561)
* (refs/tags/v0.7.0) dbd33cf Spelling fixes and README update (#559)
* (refs/tags/v0.7.0) fbb77b5 Update getting-started with install from binary distribution (#558)
* (refs/tags/v0.7.0) 4f6fc2c Create tarball from Alire workspace (#529)
* (refs/tags/v0.7.0) 7f1f9bc actions: rename post-compile into post-build and add pre-build (#537)
* (refs/tags/v0.7.0) be01f9c Updated documentation for new `alr publish` (#524)
* (refs/tags/v0.7.0) b372688 Added `user-changes.md` log for new `publish` feat
```